# Remove Rows from TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, row, tablelayout

I'm trying to Remove all rows from a TableLayoutPanel(which are added automatically at runtime) but I seem to be getting this Error:

> *Object reference not set to the instance of an object.*

Here is the code which I use:

```
    public void RemoveRows()
    {
     for (int row = BibTable.GetRowHeights().Length-1; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            BibTable.RowStyles.RemoveAt(row); //here is where i get the error
            BibTable.RowCount--;
        }
    }
```

What should I do?